# subset a time series around a specific value in a data.table

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, subset

This might be a basic question but how can you subset a time series around a specific value in a data.table? I have data:

```
DT <- data.table(time = seq(1, 14), b = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 0))
```

Now I want to look for all rows with 1 in `b` and keep, let's say 2 rows, before and after the found observation. It would be nice to have a flexible window where you define the wanted time window before and after the detected observation. The result should look like this:

```
RES <- data.table(time = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), b = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one (quick and dirty) option:

```
n <- 2L
DT[{rows <- rep(which(b==1), each = n*2L+1L) + -n:n; fifelse(rows %between% c(1,.N), rows, 0)}]

    time b
 1:    2 0
 2:    3 0
 3:    4 1
 4:    5 0
 5:    6 0
 6:   10 0
 7:   11 0
 8:   12 1
 9:   13 0
10:   14 0
```

To get the result in separate data.frames you can use lapply():

```
lapply(
  DT[b==1, which=TRUE], 
  function(i) DT[{rows <- rep(i, each = n*2L+1L) + -n:n; fifelse(rows %between% c(1,.N), rows, 0)}]
)

# [[1]]
#    time b
# 1:    2 0
# 2:    3 0
# 3:    4 1
# 4:    5 0
# 5:    6 0
# 
# [[2]]
#    time b
# 1:   10 0
# 2:   11 0
# 3:   12 1
# 4:   13 0
# 5:   14 0
```

Comment: this looks good and is working too. But what is the zero doing at the end? Is there any difference if I don't use the zero? And is there a possibilty to save the found 1 cases with its time window seperately so in this case it results in 2 seperate data.tables?

Comment: The 0 was dealing with the edge-case if the b=1 is close to the start. But there will also be an edge case if b=1 close to the edge.

Comment: Is it possible to set a start and an end index instead of a time window `n`? For example if `b = 1` then take 3 rows before and only 1 row after the oberservation. I already tried to split `n` into 2 seperate variables but got some errors.

Comment: @Bolle yes, the key is in `-n:n` you could make it `-3:1` instead.